# Filter Car Bluetooth devices by device class in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

The [Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) in Android provides a 
class ([BluetoothClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html)) for determining characteristics and capabilities of a device. Within this we can find the device class ([BluetoothClass.Device](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html)), more specifically the [AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO) class.

I intended to use this to filter the discovered devices so my application would only pair/discover bluetooth devices installed in cars, but some tests connecting to a few diferent cars from diferent brands always seem to use the [AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE) device class.

- Is the [AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE) not used in devices other than cars?
- What is the point then of having the [AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO) class?
- Is there a standard among car manufacturers?
- Is there a way to detect only car devices for sure?

Hope someone might have had the same questions and came up with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question,

1- ) Is the AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE not used in devices other than cars?

=> No, in matter of fact, you could transform your PC to any device (car, phone, handsfree), just modify your Bluetooth configuration (/etc/bluetooth/main.conf) and put your appropriate class example for A2DP:
Class = 0x20041C

2- ) What is the point then of having the AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO class?

=> I suppose that each device expose the requested services that it could use, to save more energy while using the Bluetooth as described in [Class of Device Reference](http://www.ampedrftech.com/datasheets/cod_definition.pdf)

> The main purpose of defining multiple IACs is to limit the number of
>   responses that are received when scanning devices within range.

3- ) Is there a standard among car manufacturers?

=> There is Bluetooth [profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/Profiles.aspx) standard HFP, HSP,A2DP 
And there is Class of Device (CoD) standard, you could calculate your device class ^^ see the following [calculator](http://www.ampedrftech.com/cod.htm). The manufacture only respect the Bluetooth standards (profile + class of device)

4- ) Is there a way to detect only car devices for sure?

=> I don't know exactly but i suppose that you could get the device class and compare it using the [Class of Device Reference](http://www.ampedrftech.com/datasheets/cod_definition.pdf)

Note: the pdf file source is from the official Bluetooth article [Bluetooth® Baseband](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/baseband)